# Codename One - Run iPhone app in the Xcode simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, codenameone

At the moment, I haven't a Mac and I haven't an iPhone, but I would like to see how my Codename app appears on iPhone. That's why I installed Xcode inside a MacOs inside a VMware machine... I created a blank project and launched it in the iPhone 8+ Simulator of XCode... and it works (very very slowly).

Before paying 100 euro for an Apple ID Developer and get the certificates that are necessary to build the app, my question is how can I run a Codename One app in the Xcode simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by building Codename One from sources which is a bit painful and even we don't do that. We use the build servers and include source when we need to debug in xcode. The thing is that the build servers will build your app and expect a working certificate/provisioning pair.

If you are a student your university might have an educational account you can use.

Notice you will need to pay Apple for this certificate regardless of the tool you use.

Comment: Thank you. I've just generated the "ipa" file and the source files of my app :)